# backslace remove in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am getting a value after query in database as:

```
"[\"1\", \"1006\"]"
```

How to remove \ and get array as

```
['1','1006']
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The array you posted is not an array, it is a string. Please, post the *actual* array you are having trouble with. Also, there are no backslashes in the string you posted. They are merely printed by `inspect` to escape the double quotes. They don't actually exist in the string. Observe: `'["1", "1006"]' #=> "[\"1\", \"1006\"]"`. And what does "remove backslashes" mean, exactly? In the example you posted, not only did the backslashes get removed, but also the quotes got changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is not an array, but a json string.

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse "[\"1\", \"1006\"]"
#=> ["1", "1006"]
```